# Хранить документы ВМЕСТЕ с журналом или СОВМЕСТНО с журналом?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, значение-слов

Хранить документы ВМЕСТЕ с журналом  или хранить документы СОВМЕСТНО с журналом?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 1):

СОВМЕСТНО говорит о совместных действиях

Хранить документы ВМЕСТЕ с журналом (СОВМЕСТНО с журналистом).

> СОВМЕСТНЫЙ, -ая, -ое; -тен, -тна, -тно. Осуществляемый вместе с кем-, чем-л.; общий. С-ая работа. С-ые усилия. С-ые действия авиации и флота. С-ая жизнь. С-ое обучение мальчиков и девочек. <Совместно, нареч. Действовать с. Совместно с кем-чем. в зн. предлога. =Вместе с кем-, чем-л. Операция наступления была разработана совместно с начальником штаба. Действовать совместно с общественными организациями. Совместность, -и; ж. С. действий
>   ([Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9))

Answer (score 1):

Хранить документы ВМЕСТЕ с журналом = держать их там же, где и некий журнал.

Хранить документы СОВМЕСТНО с журналом = (например) совместно с редакцией журнала заниматься архивированием документов.

Answer (score 0):

[**совместно с**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/279597)
*предл.; с твор.*; = совме́стно со
Употребляется при указании на лицо или предмет, **совместно с которыми производится действие**; вместе с чем-либо.

*Крупный канал поставки оружия из Европы в Россию перекрыла ФСБ совместно с полицией и Росгвардией.*
**Кто** производит действия? — ФСБ, полиция и Росгвардия.
Предложение можно перестроить:
ФСБ, полиция и Росгвардия совместно перекрыли крупный канал...

Наше предложение:
**Я храню документы совместно с журналом.**
**Кто** производит действие? — я и журнал?
Перестраиваем предложение: Я и журнал совместно храним документы.
Теоретически, конечно, такое возможно, но только в том случае, если под журналом подразумевается его руководство (или администрация), т. е. люди, производящие действие.

Хранить документы вместе с журналом — правильна и нейтральна такая формулировка (наверно, журнал какой-то особенный, поэтому он и хранится вместе с документами, допустим, в сейфе).